# HTML Parsing library in java

Tags: java

I am working on Selenium with java client. I am getting the Html as the string using the method `driver.getPageSource()` .

Can you please suggest to me, do we have any open source which is used to convert the Html to Java Object?

Based on that above question, I am expecting functionality like below:

- `getTextBoxIds()` - It will list of the all the text box Ids as the `HashMap()` ids as the key, and value is the TextBox value.
- `getSelectBoxIds()`
- `getDivIds()`

Note: As of now I am checking the expected data using the `contain()`, `indexOf()`, `lastIndexOf()` methods.

Regards,
Vasanth D

Comment: [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/)?

Comment: As a clarification: basically you are looking for a library to convert HTML string to typed java objects representing HTML elements.

Comment: @BackSlash sounds like an answer to me :)

Comment: ok fine , thanks , i will have look at it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do that! Selenium does it for you (and much more).

Once you're on the page you wanted to get to, you can get all the data you need:

```
/** Maps IDs of all textboxes to their value attribute. */
public Map<String,String> getTextBoxIds() {
    Map<String,String> textboxIds = new HashMap<>();

    // find all textboxes
    List<WebElement> textboxes = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[type='text']"));
    // map id of each textbox to its value
    for (WebElement textbox : textboxes) {
        textboxIds.put(textbox.getAttribute("id"), textbox.getAttribute("value"));
    }

    return textboxIds;
}
```

and so on and so forth. Look at [Selenium's documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#introducing-the-selenium-webdriver-api-by-example) to find out more.

Also, [JavaDocs](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html).

Comment: Thanks Slanec, This what i am expected . i have tested as well , the code  is working fine which is given by you.